# Google Place Autocomplete Not working in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari, google-places-api, mobile-safari

I have a google places autocomplete added to a form on my site. It works with all major browsers except Internet Explorer on Windows 10, and Old Safari for Windows, as well as the latest Safari for iOS on my iPad.

EDIT: Just realized it doesnt even work on Chrome on my iOS iPad. Odd.

```
<---HTML--->    
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places"></script>
<input type="text" id="google1" name="pick" placeholder="Pick up location" required/>
<input type="text" id="google2" name="drop" placeholder="Drop off location" required/>

<---Javascript--->
const options = {
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'sg'
  }
};

let autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('google1'), options);
autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', () => console.log(autocomplete1.getPlace()));

let autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('google2'), options);
autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', () => console.log(autocomplete2.getPlace()));
```

Is there something I did wrong that it won't work on IE and Safari? Works well everywhere else.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue

Answer (score -1):

You try to check Console Log on IE. May be to receive any error from Google API. Chrome browser will ignore it but you will find that IE & Safari are not.

[image]